# Kotlin | Priority Queue of type max heap with custom comparator

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a priority queue (max heap) for objects of the following class

```
data class Tuple(val column: Column, var count: Int)
```

where `Column` is

```
data class Column(val name: String, val dataType: String)
```

I wrote the following code to instantiate a priority queue for the above class objects with custom comparator like so:

```
val compareByCount: Comparator<Tuple> = compareByDescending { it.count }
val pq = PriorityQueue<Tuple>(compareByCount)
```

When I populate the `PriorityQueue` and perform `pq.peek()` it returns the `Tuple` object with the lowest count. Why is it so? Even though I provided a comparator that checks according to descending order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my understanding `compareByDescending` should order the elements with the biggest `count` and the beginning of the heap.

But since this is not giving you the expected result maybe you can try this out:

```
val compareByCount = Comparator<Tuple> {t1, t2 -> t1.count - t2.count}
```

Or ever simpler, without a custom comparator:

```
val pq = PriorityQueue {t1: Tuple, t2 : Tuple -> t1.count - t2.count}
```

This will add the elements to the heap in the oposite order as `compareByDescending`